# $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\,dx\,dy=$?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I'm having difficulties thinking of a good variable change for 
$$\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\,dx\,dy=?$$
the most natural choice would be something like $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$ since that would make it a very simple integral to calculate, but the bounds of $r$ and $\theta$ are all mixed up. This is a square. not a circle.

Comment: The result is $2\sinh^{-1}1=2\ln(1+\sqrt2)$.

Comment: Yes, why you do not use $$\int\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\mathrm{d} x=\sinh^{-1} x +constant?$$

Comment: @Jika: You can use that but that is a bit lengthy than the OP's original approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your substitution works. With that, you should get:
$$\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\,dx\,dy=2\int_0^{\pi/4}\int_0^{1/\cos\theta} dr\,d\theta =2\int_0^{\pi/4} \frac{d\theta}{\cos\theta}$$
Since:
$$\int_0^{\pi/4} \frac{d\theta}{\cos\theta}=\int_0^{\pi/4} \sec\theta\, d\theta=\left(\ln|\sec \theta+\tan\theta|\right|_0^{\pi/4}=\ln(\sqrt{2}+1)$$
Hence, the final result is:
$$\boxed{2\ln(\sqrt{2}+1)}$$

---

To get the bounds for $r$, consider the figure below:
[image]

From $\Delta OAC$,
$$\cos\theta=\frac{OA}{OC}=\frac{1}{OC} \Rightarrow OC=\frac{1}{\cos\theta}$$
Hence, $r$ varies from $0$ to $1/\cos\theta$.

Comment: nice. You should probably explain why the radius goes from $0$ to $1/\cos \theta$ though

Comment: Could you explain why $r$ goes from $0$ to $\frac{1}{cos\theta}$?

Comment: @OriaGruber: Sure! Consider the figure by Santosh Linkha. Draw a line at an angle $\theta$ with the horizontal axis. Do you see that the length intercepted by this line between the origin and $x=1$ is $1/\cos\theta$?

Comment: Using $y=x\tan\theta$ also works.

Comment: No....Sorry maybe I'm missing something but I don't see it. I also don't follow what Santosh said about $r_1$, the last line he wrote

Comment: @OriaGruber More simply, $0< x\leq 1$, therefore $0< r\cos(\theta)\leq 1$ which implies $0< r\leq \dfrac 1{\cos (\theta)}$.

Comment: @OriaGruber: I have added an image and some explanation. Let me know if something is still unclear.

Comment: Ok, I understand the geometric explanation perfectly now, but i have something to say about what Git said. I also thought of that, but that can't be a valid argument. since you can do the same thing with $y=rsin\theta$, $0\leq y \leq 1$ and so $r\leq \frac{1}{sin\theta}$

Comment: @OriaGruber: Those bounds you state are valid for the region $y\geq x$. Due to symmetry, we can compute the result in the region $y\le x$ and multiply the result by 2.

Answer (score 9):

Here is another way to perform the integral without using polar coordinates.

Notice the integrand and the domain to integrate are both symmetric with respect to $x \leftrightarrow y$.
This means we can split the integral into two equal pieces. One piece for $x \le y$ and another piece for $x \ge y$. On one of the piece, say $x \le y$, introduce variable $t$ such that $x = yt$, we have:

$$
\int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} dx dy 
= 2 \int_0^1 \int_0^y \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} dx dy
= 2 \int_0^1 \left(\int_0^1 \frac{1}{y\sqrt{1+t^2}} ydt\right) dy\\
= 2\int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}dt
= 2\sinh^{-1}(1)
= 2\log(\sqrt{1^2+1}+1)
= 2\log(\sqrt{2}+1)$$

Comment: Very nice and easy to understand solution!

Comment: very interesting way indeed (+1)

Comment: Yep, this is nice! :)

Answer (score 3):

you made a good guess, changing to polar is the right thing to do $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$ does the trick. Also probably you know that the Jacobian is $r$ do your integral becomes 
$$\iint \frac{1}{r}r dr d\theta$$
Since the region is a square, the bounds for theta is $0\to \pi/2$. The bounds for $r$ is varying.
[image]

So, we should split up the integral as 
$$\iint  = \int_0^{\pi/4}\int_0^{r_1} + \int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\int_0^{r_2}$$

$r_1 = \sqrt{1^2 + y^2} = \sqrt{1^2 + y^2} = \sqrt{1 + r_1 ^2 \sin^2 \theta}$ solve for $r_1$ from here ( you will get $r_1 = 1/\cos\theta $ ) and do the same for $r_2$ on the region $\mathrm{II}$

Comment: But that is exactly the problem. How can I find a definite answer if I don't know how $r$ is changing

Comment: @OriaGruber sorry, i was busy chatting on fb so I was constantly updating answer lol.

Comment: as long as it was about math, its okay :)

Comment: @OriaGruber I have updated piktaur ... does that make any sense?

Comment: makes perfect sense now :)