# Question about change of variables using Jacobian Matrix

Tags: integration

I was reading a question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/807870/int-01-int-01-frac1-sqrtx2y2-dx-dy?rq=1) talking about using a change of variables and I have recently been teaching myself how to use the determinant of the Jacobian in these situations. From my understanding, if we have a transformation from two variables $x,y$ to some other variables $u,v$ then we can say the Jacobian of the transformation $T$  given by $x=g(u,v)$ and $y=h(u,v)$ is given by:
$$\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}=\left|\begin{matrix}\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}&\frac{\partial x}{\partial v}\\\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}&\frac{\partial y}{\partial v}\end{matrix}\right|=\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}\frac{\partial y}{\partial v}-\frac{\partial x}{\partial v}\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}$$
and so in the integral we change:
$$dxdy=\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}\frac{\partial y}{\partial v}-\frac{\partial x}{\partial v}\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}\right)dudv$$

---

In the example of polar coordinates, we let $x=r\cos\theta,y=r\sin\theta$ and from this we get:
$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}=\cos\theta$$
$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial\theta}=-r\sin\theta$$
$$\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}=\sin\theta$$
$$\frac{\partial y}{\partial\theta}=r\cos\theta$$
And so we can say:
$$dxdy=\left(r\cos^2\theta+r\sin^2\theta\right)drd\theta=rdrd\theta$$
This all makes sense to me, however I find it difficult to see how you are supposed to calculate the new limits of the integral without drawing them out graphically, which I have seen done in a lot of cases. Is there a shortcut to this? Also, could this be used to change integration order? thanks

Comment: I highly recommend you do draw it out graphically. After a load of practice you may decide you no longer have to, but until then...
As for changing the order of integration https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem

Comment: also, an important technical detail is you need the absolute value of the determinant of the jacobian. So in your polar coordinate example, you should have gotten $|r|$. But since by definition $r>0$, we can remove absolute values in this case.

Comment: Does this mean by definition when we change variable we cannot say as a bound $r=0$ or is the significant part that it cannot be negative?